# Parameterised Class vs Function

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, functor, category-theory

I had a query about what is the difference between parameterising the class vs parameterising the function.

I have provided implementation of a Functor as follows:

```
trait Functor[F[_],A,B] {
  def map(fa: F[A]) (f: A => B) : F[B]
}
```

and the other where the function is parameterised as follows:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A,B](fa: F[A]) (f: A => B) : F[B]
}
```

Where are the cases where we should use one over another?

Another follow up question: 
Why do we pass the argument to functor as F[_] and not as F[A] or F[B]. What cases arise when we use either F[A] or F[B]?

Comment: Can you explain the context? What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's all up to you. If you want each instance of the `Functor` to be applicable to only a particular type of functions, go with the first option. If you want the same instance to work with any Function1, then use the second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Always** prefer the second one. With the first one you can implement instances as nonsensical as:

```
trait WrongFunctor[F[_],A,B] {
  def map(fa: F[A])(f: A => B) : F[B]
}

case class notEvenRemotelyAFunctor[A]() extends WrongFunctor[List,A,Int] {

  def map(fa: List[A])(f: A => Int) : List[Int] = 
    if(f(fa.head) < 4) List(3) else List(4)
}

type Id[X] = X
case object ILikeThree extends WrongFunctor[Id, Int, Int] {

  def map(fa: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int = if(fa == 3) 3 else f(fa)
}
```

Even if you do things right, you'd need for a fixed functor implementation one object per different types at which you want to use `fmap`. But the important point is that the second one at least makes it harder to write that kind of wrong "functors"; less non-functors will slip by:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {

  def map[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B) : F[B]
}
case object ILikeThreeAgain extends Functor[Id] {

  def map[A,B](fa: A)(f: A => B) : B =
    ??? // how do I write the above here?
}
```

The keywords here are *parametricity* and *parametric polymorphism*. The intuition is that if something is defined generically, you can derive properties it will satisfy just from the types involved. See for example [Bartosz Milewski blog - Parametricity: Money for Nothing and Theorems for Free](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/09/22/parametricity-money-for-nothing-and-theorems-for-free/) for a good explanation, or the canonical [Theorems for free](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf) paper.

#### Follow-up question

> Another follow up question: Why do we pass the argument to functor as F[_] and not as F[A] or F[B]. What cases arise when we use either F[A] or F[B]?

Because that's part of what a functor is; it is a "constructor":

1. for each input type `A` it gives you as output another type `F[A]`
2. and for each function `f: A => B`, another function `fmap(f): F[A] => F[B]` satisfying `fmap(id[A]) == id[F[A]]` and `fmap(f andThen g) == fmap(f) andThen fmap(g)`

So for 1. you need a way of representing functions *on* types; and that's what `F[_]` is.

Note that having a `map` method like in your signature is in this case equivalent to `fmap`:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {

  def map[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B) : F[B]

  def fmap[A,B](f: A => B): F[A] => F[B] =
    { fa => map(fa)(f) }

  def mapAgain[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B) : F[B] =
    fmap(f)(fa)
}
```

Now for how this links with real category theory:

Instances of your `Functor[F[_]]` trait above are meant to represent **Scala**-enriched functors

F:  **Scala** → **Scala**

Let's unpack this.

There's a (usually implicitly defined) category **Scala** with objects types, and morphisms functions f: A ⇒ B. This category is cartesian closed, where the internal hom is the *type* A ⇒ B, and the product (A,B). We can work then with **Scala**-enriched categories and functors. What's a **Scala**-enriched category? basically one that you can *define* using Scala the language: you have

1. a set of objects (which you'd need to represent as types)
2. for each A,B a type `C[A,B]` with identities `id[X]: C[X,Y]` and composition `andThen[X,Y,Z]: (C[X,Y], C[Y,Z]) => C[X,Z]` satisfying the category axioms

Enriched functors F: C → D are then

1. a function from the objects of C to those of D, `A -> F[A]`
2. for each pair of objects A,B: C a morphism in **Scala** i.e. a function `fmap: C[A,B] => C[F[A], F[B]]` satisfying the functor laws `fmap(id[A]) == id[F[A]]` and `fmap(f andThen g) == fmap(f) andThen fmap(g)`

**Scala** is naturally enriched in itself, with `Scala[X,Y] = X => Y`, and enriched functors F: **Scala** → **Scala** are what instances of your `Functor[F[_]]` trait are meant to represent.

Of course this needs all sort of qualifications about how Scala breaks this and that, morphism equality etc. But the moral of the story is: your base language **L** (like Scala in this case) is likely trying to be a cartesian-closed (or at least symmetric monoidal-closed) category, and functors definable through it correspond to **L**-enriched functors.

Comment: +1 on mentioning Wadler's paper and Milewski's blog post. In short, an one instance of `WrongFunctor` is not a functor. To be a functor it should be F[_] "mappable" over any `A` and `B`.

Comment: Hi @eduardo, I have a follow up question, can you also answer this query?